# Scala Applicatives?

Tags: scala, applicative

In Scala, how can I append an `Option[A]` to `Option[A]`:

Meaning:

`Some("foo") ??? Some("bar") == Some("foobar")`

In Haskell I'd use an applicative:

```
ghci>import Control.Applicative
ghci> (++) <$> (Just "foo") <*> (Just "bar")
Just "foobar"
```

Are there `Applicatives` in Scala's standard Typesafe library?

Comment: Note that in this specific case if you're using Scalaz the semigroup instance for `Option[A: Semigroup]` is a little clearer—you just write `a |+| b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) you can do it this way:

```
  import scalaz.syntax.applicative._
  import scalaz.std.option._

  val l: Option[String] = Some("foo")
  val r: Option[String] = Some("bar")
  val result = ^(l, r)(_ + _)
  println(result) // Some("foobar")
```

Answer (score 2):

Applicatives aren't in the standard library, but you can use for-comprehensions like monads in Haskell:

```
for {
  l <- Some("foo")
  r <- Some("bar")
} yield (l + r)
```

(or rewrite it with `flatMap`, of course). Otherwise, go with scalaz, as in Eugene's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to achieve this particular syntax, you can combine an implicit class with a monad for-comprehension:

```
implicit class RichOption(a: Option[String]) {
  def ???(b: Option[String]) = for (sa <- a; sb <- b) yield sa+sb
}

scala> Some("foo") ??? Some("bar") == Some("foobar")
res4: Boolean = true
```